# How to tell Visual Studio 2008 which folders it should search for library files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

For some reason I get this:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32.lib'
```

But when I copy that library to Visual Studio 2008 folder, it works. How do I tell my Visual Studio 2008 that it should seek for the library files from the same folder where my project file is? I tried looking all the project settings, but couldn't find anything different to my working project, which indeed searches libraries from that folder where the project file is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Project > Properties (or press ALT + F7), under "Configuration Properties" select "Linker", and under that, "General" , here you should see "Additional Library Directories", add your paths there.

Comment: Nevermind about my last 2 comments I removed; I got it working, something was messed up, I'm not sure what, but now it works!

Comment: @Rookie go back to "Linker", under that > `Input` > `Additional dependencies` , here add the name of `.lib` file only (without the path), make sure the dir that contains this `.lib` file is in `Additional Library Directories`